# Can someone provide an example of shrine/rails with multiple images?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shrine

my rails app has an model named listing and for a listing i need to upload multiple photos.
so the Photo model also has a position so i can order them.
trying to do this with shrine despite all the information all attempts fail.
can someone provide a working example including the controller and model
model listing
name
has_many :photos

model photo
image_data
position:integer

Answer (score 1):

You can find an example here : https://github.com/ebaudet/DemoShrine